# override the new package with the old one

Tags: java

Considering a java application with a embedded `X` impl/jar file, for example `com.test` package.
and we cannot change and modify the jar file.
Now suppose I have a `X1.jar` file which is modified version of exist `X(com.test)` package.

**Question:**
Is it possible to override the `X1.jar` implementation with embedded(exist) implementation just before the library gets loaded? and again, assume we cannot change the package anyway.
I'd like that to redirect all the types under `com.test` package to the new one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just extend the classes you want to modify and use these?

Comment: @m0skit0 cannot modify or alter the jar file, application uses `com.test` package, and I cannot just override or change the business code, all I want to do is redirect(override, hack, ...) the exist `com.test` objects(requests) to the new definition.

Comment: You don't need modify the JAR file. I mean extend the classes. What do you mean by *"new definition"*? It's not clear why you want to modify existing classes package.

Comment: What you would like is for the public api to be loaded from the first jar file and the implementation from the second. That can't happen. The first jar to be loaded will load its own implementation with it and the second will be discarded.

Comment: @m0skit0 I cannot change any code, there is a `x.jar` package(api) embedded to a jar file, and I wan to change it with the new `x0.jar`

Comment: You don't need change anything you can just extend and put in new package. You should check about inheritance.

Comment: @m0skit0 I see you dear, but suppose a `app.jar` file which contains `com.test` package, and I cannot change anything inside and it's sealed. now I have a new jar file which contains new version of `com.test` and I wish the `app.jar` uses the new definition instead of embedded ones. i really cannot change anything inside.

Comment: Dude, really, what part of *"You don't need change anything"* you didn't understand? You're lacking basic Java knowledge. As I said, go learn about inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

As per m0skit0's suggestion:

Orig class:

```
package example.x
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(String neededVar)
    {...}

    public String someMethod(String someVar)
    {
        // original implementation
    }
}
```

Custom class:

```
import example.x.SomeClass
public class MySomeClass extends SomeClass
{
    public MySomeClass(String neededVar)
    {
        super(neededVar);
        // anything else
    }

    @Override
    public String someMethod(String someVar)
    {
        // implement differently
        super.someMethod(someVar);
        // or add to it
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I cannot modify anything

Comment: You are not modifying the original jar, you are building on top of it leaving everything intact and untouched. In your implementation you will be calling your custom classes instead of the original ones that inherit all original functionality while having access to any additions you make or enhance. Perhaps you need to better clarify your restrictions, involved jars or apps and where/how you use them.

Comment: I see you dear, and I know enough about OOP concepts, but assume I just can inherit and implement my new implementation, so what next? I have to tell the exist system to use the new classes instead of old one, right? I cannot do this.

Comment: I'll put the condescending tone down to translation difficulties. As for your problem, if you have no access to the implementation code then how do you expect to modify how it does anything? This is beginning to smell suspicious...